# UDP Socket the client does not recieve a message from server

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

This is a server code by python

```
from socket import *


serverPort = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

print(" the server is ready to receive")

while 1:
     message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
     modifiedMessage = message.upper()
serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

and the client code is

```
from socket import * 
serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input ('Input lowercase sentense:')
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

I run the server first the output is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtbVJ.png)

Then I run client and enter the lowercase sentence after that the client and server does't do anything else

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou88p.png)

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while 1:
    message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)`
```

Indentation in Python is important. Your server process will never reach the third statement as it is technically positioned after the end of an infinite loop.

Comment: THIS IS THE FIRST TIME TO DEAL WITH PYTHON, I SOLVE THE PROBLEM  BY ADDING INDENTATION, THANK YOU FOR HELP